# PRAW: Captcha Problems

Tags: python, praw

In my bot when there's an error it sends my account a message but when I was testing it gave me a URL to the picture for the captcha and an area to enter it.  How can I avoid this?
Code

```
import praw

username = ("SECRET")
password = ("SECRET")

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="SECRET SECRET")

r.login(username, password)
r.send_message("SECRET", "SECRET", "Test!")

submissionsTop = r.get_subreddit("SECRET").get_top(limit=5)

submissionsHot = r.get_subreddit("SECRET").get_hot(limit=5)
[str(x) for x in submissionsTop]
[str(x) for x in submissionsHot]
```

Secret Is just stuff I don't want you to know like passwords

Comment: Don't completely understand the subject, but doesn't sending the message by hand normally require confirming your action with a CaptCha? Usually this is done to prevent botting, so... that would be your answer?

Comment: So then what would the point of adding the r.send_message function to PRAW

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with karma. If you don't have enough karma, the reddit API prevents you from sending a message without first clearing a captcha.